# Why magento 2 redirection from onepage not working?

Tags: magento2, cart, shipping-address, programmatically, place-order

My code in onepage.phtml for redirecting automatically for payment page when a specific product is added to cart.

```
<?php 

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 

// retrieve quote items collection
$itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();

// get array of all items what can be display directly
$itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

// retrieve quote items array
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach($items as $item) {// product id 
    $it[] = $item->getProductId();
}
if (in_array(482, $it)){
    header("Location: https://test.rkhomeappliances.co.in/checkout/#payment"); exit; 
}


?>
```

Comment: You should not add these code lines directly to phtml template.

Comment: Seem that you want to redirect payment gateway when navigating checkout page?

Comment: Yes when a specific product is on cart I need to redirect to payment gateway. But that redirection throws exception. Can you please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use direct link in your code.

But as I can identify you have used `#payment` in redirect URL which will be redirecting to you directly on checkout step2 which is payment method selection. While it should be redirect to step 1 so just **remove** `#payement` from your URL and you will see it's working.

On step1 you will get shipping address and method form. So for physical product you have to set shipping address and method before payment.

Comment: Sorry I need to redirect directly to payment page. If I need to redirect directly to payment gateway there is any options? If I made digital product is there is any options to redirect to payment gateway?